# SQL query should aggregate data per row instead of multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I want the total views to be listed per row of survey taken:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `survey` (
      `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `title` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      `url` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    INSERT INTO `survey` (`id`, `title`, `url`) VALUES
      ('1', 'ants on the hill', 'https://mypoll.io/xyz'),
      ('2', 'crocs in the swamp', 'https://mypoll.io/xyz'),
      ('3', 'baboon on the loose', 'https://mypoll.io/another-term.');


      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `views` (
      `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `poll_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `count` int(6) NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
       FOREIGN KEY (poll_id) REFERENCES survey(id)
    ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    INSERT INTO `views` (`id`, `poll_id`, `count`) VALUES
      ('1', 1, 1),
      ('2', 2, 1),
      ('3', 2, 1),
       ('4', 3, 1);
```

What i currently have:

```
SELECT s.*, COALESCE(v.totalViews, 0) as totalViews 
          FROM survey s
          LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, poll_id, count(id) AS totalViews
          FROM views GROUP BY id) as v on v.poll_id = s.id
```

I want the results to eventually look like this

```
id  title               url                     totalViews
1   ants on the hill    https://mypoll.io/xyz   1
2   crocs in the swamp  https://mypoll.io/xyz   2
3   baboon on the loose https://mypoll.io/another-term. 1
```

Sample Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb8ede/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining and aggregating on the wrong column.  You just want `poll_id`:

```
SELECT s.*, COALESCE(v.totalViews, 0) as totalViews 
FROM survey s LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT poll_id, count(id) AS totalViews
      FROM views 
      GROUP BY poll_id
     ) v
     ON v.poll_id = s.id;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb8ede/2) is a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a minor adjustment to your sub-query, remove `id` column from the SELECT since it isn't needed and do GROUP BY on `poll_id` instead

```
SELECT poll_id, count(id) AS totalViews
      FROM views GROUP BY poll_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you rather use `sum(count)` (instead of `count(id)`) in your query?

```
SELECT poll_id,title,url, sum(`count`) totalViews FROM survey s
LEFT JOIN views v ON v.poll_id= s.id
GROUP BY poll_id
```

Otherwise the actual `count` in `views` will not be considered in your result.

See [my fiddle for a demo](https://rextester.com/IRW21229)